# MongoDB service not starting on RedHat - missing 'service_uri'

Tags: mongodb, redhat

I'm on a `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.4 (Tikanga)` machine

I created my `/etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo` like this:

```
[10gen]
name=10gen Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

I installed MongoDB with: `sudo yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server`

but when I run: `sudo service mongod start`

I get: `Missing SERVICE_URI environment variable`

help! :)

Answer (score 19):

You have an executable in `PATH` called `service` that is not the standard utility that starts services. Use `/sbin/service` instead of `service`.

Answer (score 4):

Does `/etc/init.d/mongod start` work?

If so, something has overloaded the `service` command - in which case, the simplest thing to do is just use `/etc/init.d/mongod start`